# Why can't I find my File?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, file-io, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to open a CSV file name "logger.csv" which I have saved in the source folder itself.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename = "logger.csv";
    File motor_readings = new File(filename);
    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(motor_readings);
        while (inputStream.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(inputStream.next());
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: File not found!");
    }
}
```

However, this keeps on giving me a "File not found" error.

Comment: I'm not sure that's relevant Andreas, if you read their question - they aren't actually asking how to read "CSV" files using Java, it's more of "opening any file" using java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use relative pathing as you are right now - the file needs to exist in the project root, **not** in the directory of the java file.

Consider this hierarchy:

```
project/
  src/main/java
    file.java
    logger.csv
```

`new File("logger.csv")` will not work.

```
project/
  logger.csv
  src/main/java
    file.java
```

`new File("logger.csv")` will *now* work. (notice, the file is adjacent to the src directory.)

Comment: It works but its only giving me partial file. Like only a few readings. It cuts out the beginning.

Comment: @GReaper check if logger,csv is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Put the file on level up. In the main folder of the project.

Comment: how do I use the full path?

Comment: @GReaper2478 Just put it in front of your filename - or try the code in my answer to see where the file has been expected.

Answer (score 0):

To see where the file is expected update the code in your catch clause to:

```
        System.out.println("Error: File not found: " + motor_readings.getAbsolutePath());
```

Put it there and be sure to refresh your workspace in Eclipse so that the file can be seen.